# Pageee jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have recently written a jQuery plugin called [Pageee](https://github.com/JacquesMarais/Pageee).

> Pageee is a jQuery plugin to scroll through full pages automatically, by arrow buttons, or by dragging the page.

I have now come to Code Review to ask you if you have any suggestions to the code appearance (readability), the browser support (should only support modern browsers, IE 11+), the performance, and the overall quality of the code. Here is the JavaScript.

```
(function($) {
    $.pageee = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === "undefined") {
            options = {};
        }
        if (typeof options === "object") {
            options = $.extend({
                dragScroll: true,
                keyScroll: true,
                autoScroll: false,
                pageSelector: ".pageee",
                customStyles: false,
                interval: 3000
            }, options);
        }

        if (!options.customStyles) {
            $("<style>                               \
                .pageee {                            \
                    -webkit-touch-callout: none;     \
                    -webkit-user-select: none;       \
                    -khtml-user-select: none;        \
                    -moz-user-select: none;          \
                    -ms-user-select: none;           \
                    user-select: none;               \
                    width: 100%;                     \
                    height: 100%;                    \
                    position: fixed;                 \
                    top: 0;                          \
                    left: 0;                         \
                }                                    \
                .pageee-hidden {                     \
                    z-index: 0;                      \
                }                                    \
                .pageee-top {                        \
                    top: -100%;                      \
                }                                    \
                .pageee-bottom {                     \
                    top: 100%;                       \
                }                                    \
                .pageee-over {                       \
                    z-index: 200;                    \
                }                                    \
                .pageee-shown {                      \
                    z-index: 100;                    \
                }                                    \
            </style>").appendTo("head");
        }

        var page = 1;
        var lastPage = parseInt($(".pageee").eq(-1).data("pageee"), 10);
        var previousPage = lastPage;
        var nextPage = 2;
        $(options.pageSelector + ":last").addClass("pageee-top");
        $(options.pageSelector).not(":last, :eq(" + (page - 1) + ")").addClass("pageee-bottom");
        $(options.pageSelector).addClass("pageee-hidden").removeClass("pageee-shown");
        $("[data-pageee=" + page + "]").toggleClass("pageee-shown pageee-hidden");
        var previousPageElm = $("[data-pageee=" + previousPage + "]"),
            originalPrevTop = parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10);
        var nextPageElm = $("[data-pageee=" + nextPage + "]"),
            originalNextTop = parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10);
        var pageChangeAllowed = true;
        window.__pageeeChange = 0;
        $(document).on("pageee-change", function(e, pageNum) {
            if (!pageChangeAllowed) {
                pageChangeAllowed = false;
                window.clearTimeout(window.__pageeeChange);
                window.__pageeeChange = window.setTimeout(function() {
                    pageChangeAllowed = true;
                }, 300);
                return false;
            }
            $("[data-pageee=" + pageNum + "]").stop().animate({
                top: 0
            });
            $("[data-pageee=" + page + "]").toggleClass("pageee-shown pageee-hidden");
            $(options.pageSelector).removeClass("pageee-over pageee-top pageee-bottom");
            page = pageNum;
            previousPage = page == 1 ? lastPage : page - 1;
            nextPage = page == lastPage ? 1 : page + 1;
            previousPageElm = $("[data-pageee=" + previousPage + "]");
            previousPageElm.addClass("pageee-top").css("top", "-100%");
            originalPrevTop = parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10);
            nextPageElm = $("[data-pageee=" + nextPage + "]");
            nextPageElm.addClass("pageee-bottom").css("top", "100%");
            originalNextTop = parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10);
            $("[data-pageee=" + page + "]").toggleClass("pageee-shown pageee-hidden").removeClass("pageee-top pageee-bottom");
            if (options.autoScroll) {
                clearInterval(window.__pageeeAuto);
                window.__pageeeAuto = window.setInterval(function() {
                    $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
                }, options.interval);
            }
            pageChangeAllowed = false;
            window.clearTimeout(window.__pageeeChange);
            window.__pageeeChange = window.setTimeout(function() {
                pageChangeAllowed = true;
            }, 300);
        });

        if (options.dragScroll) {
            console.log("t");
            var mouseDown = false,
                clickY, originalClickY, prevMouseY = 0,
                scrollingTo = null;
            $(document).on({
                mousedown: function(e) {
                    mouseDown = true;
                    prevMouseY = e.pageY;
                    originalClickY = e.pageY;
                },
                mousemove: function(e) {
                    if (mouseDown) {
                        if (originalClickY < e.pageY) {
                            nextPageElm.removeClass("pageee-over").css("top", "100%");
                            previousPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                            if (prevMouseY < e.pageY) clickY = 3;
                            else if (prevMouseY > e.pageY) clickY = -3;
                            else return false;
                            previousPageElm.css("top", parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10) + clickY);
                            prevMouseY = e.pageY;
                            scrollingTo = -1;
                        } else if (e.pageY < originalClickY) {
                            previousPageElm.removeClass("pageee-over").css("top", "-100%");
                            nextPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                            if (prevMouseY < e.pageY) clickY = 3;
                            else if (prevMouseY > e.pageY) clickY = -3;
                            else return false;
                            nextPageElm.css("top", parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) + clickY);
                            prevMouseY = e.pageY;
                            scrollingTo = +1;
                        }
                    }
                },
                mouseup: function(e) {
                    if (mouseDown) {
                        if (!pageChangeAllowed) {
                            pageChangeAllowed = false;
                            window.clearTimeout(window.__pageeeChange);
                            window.__pageeeChange = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                pageChangeAllowed = true;
                            }, 300);
                            previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                                top: "-100%"
                            });
                            nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                                top: "100%"
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                        mouseDown = false;
                        if (scrollingTo < 0) {
                            if (0 - (originalPrevTop - parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10)) > 40) {
                                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", previousPage);
                                originalClickY = 0;
                                clickY = 0;
                                prevMouseY = 0;
                                scrollingTo = null;
                            } else {
                                previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                                    top: "-100%"
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (originalNextTop - parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) > 40) {
                                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
                                originalClickY = 0;
                                clickY = 0;
                                prevMouseY = 0;
                                scrollingTo = null;
                            } else {
                                nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                                    top: "100%"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $(document).on({
                touchstart: function(e) {
                    mouseDown = true;
                    prevMouseY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                    originalClickY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                },
                touchmove: function(e) {
                    if (mouseDown) {
                        if (originalClickY < e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) {
                            nextPageElm.removeClass("pageee-over").css("top", "100%");
                            previousPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                            if (prevMouseY < e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) clickY = 3;
                            else if (prevMouseY > e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) clickY = -3;
                            else return false;
                            previousPageElm.css("top", parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10) + clickY);
                            prevMouseY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                            scrollingTo = -1;
                        } else if (e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY < originalClickY) {
                            previousPageElm.removeClass("pageee-over").css("top", "-100%");
                            nextPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                            if (prevMouseY < e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) clickY = 3;
                            else if (prevMouseY > e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY) clickY = -3;
                            else return false;
                            nextPageElm.css("top", parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) + clickY);
                            prevMouseY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                            scrollingTo = +1;
                        }
                    }
                },
                touchend: function(e) {
                    if (mouseDown) {
                        if (!pageChangeAllowed) {
                            pageChangeAllowed = false;
                            window.clearTimeout(window.__pageeeChange);
                            window.__pageeeChange = window.setTimeout(function() {
                                pageChangeAllowed = true;
                            }, 300);
                            previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                                top: "-100%"
                            });
                            nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                                top: "100%"
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                        mouseDown = false;
                        if (scrollingTo < 0) {
                            if (0 - (originalPrevTop - parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10)) > 40) {
                                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", previousPage);
                                originalClickY = 0;
                                clickY = 0;
                                prevMouseY = 0;
                                scrollingTo = null;
                            } else {
                                previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                                    top: "-100%"
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (originalNextTop - parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) > 40) {
                                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
                                originalClickY = 0;
                                clickY = 0;
                                prevMouseY = 0;
                                scrollingTo = null;
                            } else {
                                nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                                    top: "100%"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (options.keyScroll) {
            var scrollingTo = null,
                allowed = true;
            $(document).on({
                keydown: function(e) {
                    if (!pageChangeAllowed) {
                        pageChangeAllowed = false;
                        window.clearTimeout(window.__pageeeChange);
                        window.__pageeeChange = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            pageChangeAllowed = true;
                        }, 300);
                        previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                            top: "-100%"
                        });
                        nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                            top: "100%"
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!allowed) return false;
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (code == 38) {
                        previousPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                        previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                            top: parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10) + 40
                        });
                        scrollingTo = -1;
                    } else if (code == 40) {
                        nextPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                        nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                            top: parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) - 40
                        });
                        scrollingTo = 1;
                    }
                    allowed = false;
                },
                keyup: function(e) {
                    if (scrollingTo < 0) {
                        $(document).trigger("pageee-change", previousPage);
                    } else {
                        $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
                    }
                    allowed = true;
                }
            });
        }
        if (options.autoScroll) {
            window.__pageeeAuto = window.setInterval(function() {
                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
            }, options.interval);
        }
        return {
            next: function() {
                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", nextPage);
            },
            prev: function() {
                $(document).trigger("pageee-change", previousPage);
            },
            revealNext: function() {
                nextPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                nextPageElm.stop().animate({
                    top: parseInt(nextPageElm.css("top"), 10) - 40
                });
            },
            revealPrev: function() {
                previousPageElm.addClass("pageee-over");
                previousPageElm.stop().animate({
                    top: parseInt(previousPageElm.css("top"), 10) + 40
                });
            },
            $: $,
            jQuery: $
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I also added some CSS for in case the `<style>` element won't append to the `<head>` element. Here is the CSS.

```
.pageee {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.pageee-hidden { 
    z-index: 0;
}
.pageee-top {
    top: -100%;
}
.pageee-bottom { 
    top: 100%; 
}
.pageee-over { 
    z-index: 200;
}
.pageee-shown {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I believe you should extend this plugin to support all browsers.